# Spring in Websphere Application Server

Tags: spring, websphere, websphere-8, ibm-rad

I'm working on a project which using JSF-Spring-Hibernate and run on Tomcat and Jetty. I got to run it with Websphere Application Server(V8). I've tried to do this, but I cant. I created a Enterprise Application from admin console. I put my project war to this configuration and  I gave Context as my project root directory. After it was created, i tried to start it but   there are some exceptions like  `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:` 
`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:` 
`javax.faces.FacesException:` 
`java.net.URISyntaxException:`

there are also

```
[26.02.2012 14:59:12:900 VET] 00000173 SystemErr R SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. 
[26.02.2012 14:59:12:900 VET] 00000173 SystemErr R SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://216.fwk37593285:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] 
[26.02.2012 14:59:12:900 VET] 00000173 SystemErr R SLF4J: Found binding in [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv0‌​1/installedApps/Toshiba-TOSHNode01Cell/docboxs-war.ear/docbox.war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

I'm newbie about IBM products can someone tell what i should do.

Comment: Please edit the post rather than posting a comment.

Comment: I had similar problem when I pasted different versions log4j *.jar libraries to my lib directory. Check this out, if no try to remove your slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar from docbox.war/WEB-INF/lib. That library will rather useful during compile than deploy. It seemed like WebSphere alread had local library of log4j.

Comment: So should i remove these libraries from my project ? İ've checked websphere library but i dont see slf4j and log4j libraries.